# How can I make heroku/nodejs buildpack dump yarn logs into console instead of a tmp file?

Tags: node.js, heroku, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

Everything's sort of in the question, but here's some details. I have an monorepo structure like this, built on yarn workspaces:

```
my_app/
├─ node_modules/
├─ packages/
│  ├─ backend/
│  │  ├─ package.json/
│  │  ├─ Procfile/
│  ├─ frontend/
│  │  ├─ package.json/
│  │  ├─ Procfile/
│  ├─ common/
│  │  ├─ package.json/
├─ package.json/
├─ yarn.lock/
```

`backend` and `frontend` each depend on `common`, but not each other.

`backend` and `frontend` need to be deployed to Heroku. I used the [heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi-procfile](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi-procfile) buildpack to set a Procfile per each application. So the buildpacks for backend are:

```
1. heroku/nodejs
2. heroku-community/multi-procfile
```

And for frontend:

```
1. mars/create-react-app
2. heroku-community/multi-procfile
```

> Note: [mars/create-react-app](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack) uses heroku/nodejs for its build step, so it looks like the issue is with that one.

As I push each one of them, they result in the same error that happens at Yarn's link step:

```
remote:        ➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
remote:        ➤ YN0062: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A2.3.2#~builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=2.3.2&hash=1cc4b2 The platform linux is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
remote:        ➤ YN0062: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A1.2.13#~builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=1.2.13&hash=1cc4b2 The platform linux is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
remote:        ➤ YN0008: │ my-app@workspace:. must be rebuilt because its dependency tree changed
remote:        ➤ YN0008: │ bcrypt@npm:5.0.1 must be rebuilt because its dependency tree changed
remote:        ➤ YN0008: │ @nestjs/core@npm:8.1.1 [496a1] must be rebuilt because its dependency tree changed
remote:        ➤ YN0009: │ my-app@workspace:. couldn't be built successfully (exit code 127, logs can be found here: /tmp/xfs-9791b677/build.log)
remote:        ➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 7s 955ms
remote:        ➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 1m 11s
```

As you see, it seems like it tries to build the root workspace (possibly that's the way it gets to build `common`?) and fails. It dumps its logs into a file, but as far as I know, it's impossible to see files generated during build process.

Here are my questions then:

1. Is there a way to make it dump logs explicitly in the console?
2. How can I simulate the same deploy process on my local? I looked through Heroku CLI docs and heroku/nodejs, but found only logs on running, not deploying.

Thanks for getting all the way down here! I must mention that I started working with Heroku yesterday, so I might still be missing something obvious - their logs are easy to get lost in. It's not my first time working with a managed software and I understand their general architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally realized how to simulate the process on local: heroku/nodejs actually logs every step and every command it runs. You can find them, if in the dashboard you go to Your app -> Activity -> View build log (on one of the failed ones).

In my case `yarn workspaces focus --all --production` was failing and the problem was that I had a `postinstall` script that was installing husky, but husky itself is a dev dependency. I changed the postinstall script to `prepare`, which is postinstall that runs on dev only and it fixed the problem.